# Rounding df index along with its data to nearest interval

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series dataframe with a DateTimeIndex, based on sensor data which sometimes arrives a bit early or a bit late. It looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(3), index=pd.DatetimeIndex([
                 '2021-01-01 08:00', '2021-01-01 08:04', '2021-01-01 08:11']))
> df
2021-01-01 08:00:00     1.0
2021-01-01 08:04:00     1.0
2021-01-01 08:11:00     1.0
```

I'd like to rearrange it to match five-minute intervals without losing any data. I tried:

```
df.reindex(df.index.round('5 min'))
```

but it drops the data not matching the intervals:

```
2021-01-01 08:00:00     1.0
2021-01-01 08:05:00     NaN
2021-01-01 08:10:00     NaN
```

Is there a way to get this?

```
2021-01-01 08:00:00     1.0
2021-01-01 08:05:00     1.0
2021-01-01 08:10:00     1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `method='nearest'` in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.round('5 min'), method='nearest')
print (df)
    
                       0
2021-01-01 08:00:00  1.0
2021-01-01 08:05:00  1.0
2021-01-01 08:10:00  1.0
```